# Is lexicographical sorting with highest length first possible in python?

Tags: python, sorting

Let's say I have a list

`list = ['aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'cc']`

if you do `list.sort()`
you get back
 `['aa', 'aa', 'aaa', 'bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'cc']`

Is there a way in **python 3** we can get

`['aaa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bbbb', 'bbb', 'bb', 'cc']`

So within the same lexicographical group order, pick the one with the bigger length first.

Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Please edit the code of your attempt to solve this into your question.

Comment: What are the rules for the strings? Can "bzb" be in there?

Comment: ya bzb can be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine what less-than means for the strings with a custom class. Use that class as the key for `list.sort` or `sorted`.

```
class C:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self, other):
        min_len = min((len(self.val), len(other.val)))
        if self.val[:min_len] == other.val[:min_len]:
            return len(self.val) > len(other.val)
        else:
            return self.val < other.val

lst = ['aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'cc']
slist = sorted(lst, key=C)
print(slist)
```

Comment: `sorted` already returns a list; you don't need to call `list` on the result.

Comment: @stef - good point. I assume everything is an iterator these days.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are ordered lexicographically, so you can use a tuple of (first character of string, negative length) as the sort key:

```python
list.sort(key=lambda s: (s[0], -len(s)))
```

Comment: @tdelaney: My answer covers all test cases in the question. 100% of all the examples in the question only have strings of identical characters, and there is no specification in the question that there can ever possibly be a string that does not consist of anything but a single repeated character, so I don't think that needs to be considered.

Comment: @RexAex - Even then it depends on where it is in the list. In this world, only the first letter and size matter for sorting. Try `["bzb", "bab"]`. The result is still  `["bzb", "bab"]`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ... and I asked OP to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You were able to explain in words how to compare two strings, so you can write this comparison function in python. However, since python 3, `.sort()` and `sorted()` both expect a **`key`**, rather than a comparison function.

- You can turn the comparison function into a key by using a class and defining its method `.__lt__`, as explained in [tdelaney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64871192/3080723);
- Or you can use [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key), which was designed specifically for this purpose.

`cmp_to_key` expects a comparison function which returns -1, 0 or +1 respectively for less than, equal or greater than.

```py
def custom_compare_strings(s1, s2):
  length = min(len(s1), len(s2))
  if s1[:length] == s2[:length]:
    return len(s2) - len(s1)
  else:
    return -1 if s1 < s2 else +1

lst = ['aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'cc']

import functools
slist = sorted(lst, key=functools.cmp_to_key(custom_compare_strings))
print(slist)
# ['aaa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bbbb', 'bbb', 'bb', 'cc']
```

Comment: The result is slightly off.

Comment: I think he meant it should be return len(s2) - len(s1) not the other way around. Also shouldn't it be return -1 if s1 < s2 else 0 as well?

Comment: @RexAex Oops, you're right about `len(s2) - len(s1)`. For the other remark: return value 0 is only for equal strings; the strings can't be equal if we're in the `else` branch.